# Windows 10 Outlook will not connect over VPN

Tags: networking, windows-10, microsoft-outlook, vpn

Been seeing this issue, hope someone else has solved. 
When my windows 10 users are connected to VPN, outlook will not connect. No errors, just tries to connect and goes to disconnected. Network drives work properly, hostnames resolve, just Outlook not connecting.

When not connected to VPN, Outlook connects fine. However then users do not have network shares etc.

Have not seen this on any Win7 or 8 users.

Details - Windows 10, Office 2013, Watchguard VPN, Exchange 2010.

Comment: Are you the VPN administrator?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of vpn are you using, Windows built-in vpn or some vpn software?
If using Windows built-in vpn, then try this solution:

If you've never used Power Shell, it's pretty easy.  In Win10,  go to "Start"  then find the folder for "Windows Power Shell" click the > to open the folder in the menu, and select the program "Windows Power Shell" by right-clicking on it and selecting "run as administrator."

The Power Shell window will then pop up. If you don't see it, it may be hidden by whatever else you have on your screen.  But it will be there.

At the command line,  just enter the first command, without the quotes

"Get-VpnConnection"

This will return a detailed listing of the settings for your Microsoft built-in VPN client adapter that you've already set up to connect remotely to a server, i.e., it will show all the settings for each VPN.

Next, perform the second command without the quotes

"Set-VpnConnection -Name "myVPN" -SplitTunneling $True"

Be sure to insert the actual name of your own VPN (whatever you named it and what is shown next to "Name" after you perform the first command and get the settings returned) in the space for "myVPN", but be sure to place the command  "-Name" before it.

Once you've typed in both commands, hit Enter.

The commands are case-sensitive, so be mindful of that.

Once you've entered both commands, nothing will happen, no pop-ups or anything.
Just quit powershell and try to connect to your vpn

Comment: Using the Watchguard SSL VPN Client

Comment: Thanks for this fix - it worked for me. Take the case sensitive part seriously! As an old newbie, I assumed that PowerShell, being a DOS prompt, was not case sensitive, but it is! Also, be sure your VPN name has no spaces in it. You can edit it easily thru VPN setup in Options. [sarah](https://superuser.com/users/960355/sarah)

Comment: Im on PulseVPN (store app) the comand is successful, the split tunnel is shown as true afterwards ..... but no change in my networking

Comment: just FYI, this *does NOT* make Outlook work over a VPN, it allows Outlook to *bypass* the VPN and use your regular network connexion.  so your Outlook traffic is NOT being routed through the VPN, it's being routed through your baseline network.